# How to Read a Property File in a Maven Project?

Tags: maven, properties, resources

I've read all the related entries on this topic but nothing is working.

I have placed the database property file under resources/property/db.properties, added the following to Maven:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/property/db.properties</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and using the following code to get the stream:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("db.properties");
```

but when the Properties object loads it, it strangely only contains a single property defined in pom.xml (which is an encoding property)!

I have tried the following as well at no avail:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("property/db.properties");
```

I can see that the file is at target's class/property/db.properties (or in latter case, in class/db.properties) when the project gets built and deployed (Tomcat). Is there something I am missing here?

**UPDATE**

As it is suggested in the comment below, use "/" to prefix the path to the property file.

If you want to do it using properties-maven-plugin, make sure property values are indicated in `Properties` section of POM.xml. This plugin then grabs these values and puts them in a property file indicated by `outputFile` tag.

Comment: `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/property/db.properties");`

Comment: @khmarbaise Here's what I have found after prefixing forward slash: the property object doesn't get loaded with any data as before, however, if I pass in the stream to a buffer reader and iterate through the property file line by line, it outputs everything just fine. Looking into Properties.load() method, initially I thought that a value of one of my properties might have caused an issue (contains ":"), but ever after removing it and restarting the application, it still doesn't load the properties!!!

Comment: without the code it's impossible to say where the issue is..I don't understand the realtionship to properties-maven-plugin ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I believe, what I was seeing is expected. The build block basically grabs properties defined in POM.xml itself and puts them in a property file which can then be streamed as a resource. You were actually correct about the forward slash. I actually ended up just creating a separate property files and use `Resourcebundle` to parse it for the application.